# Is there a way to make a function more generic in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function, generics

I'm writing a few functions for datasets, and I'm wondering if there's a way to write these functions to make them work on multiple data sets where columns may have different names.

```
def calc(df):
    a = df.groupby(['Region', 'Year'], as_index=False)["Sales"].sum()
    print(a.to_string(index=False))
```

This function works without any issues, as I specify the column names. Is there anyway to do something like this:

```
def calc(df, x1, x2, x3):
    a = df.groupby([x1, x2], as_index=False)[x3].sum()
    print(a.to_string(index=False))
```

And put values in like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    report2(df, df['Region'], df['Year'], df["Sales"])
```

When I try to do this I always get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sales_record.py", line 60, in <module>
    calc(df, df['Region'], df['Year'], df["Sales"])
  File "sales_record.py", line 54, in calc
    answer = df.groupby([x1, x2], as_index=False)[x3].sum()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 265, in __getitem__
    .format(missing=str(bad_keys)[1:-1]))
KeyError: 'Columns not found: 7200, 22500, 82500, 1800, 45000, 9000, 99000, 18000, 22000, 8400, 110000, 16500, 54000, 112500, 3000'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You nearly had it. You just called your function with the wrong parameters: `df['Region'], df['Year'], df['Sales']` instead of `'Region', 'Year', 'Sales'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is call `columns names`:

```
calc(df, 'Region', 'Year', "Sales")
```

Your solution should be a bit changed for working - passing also Series instead `DaatFrame` - check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) - it is also called syntactic sugar:

```
def calc1(x1, x2, x3):
    a = x3.groupby([x1, x2], as_index=False).sum()
    print(a.to_string(index=False))

calc1(df['Region'], df['Year'], df["Sales"])
```

Comment: I see, I thought when using pandas and calling column you always had to do the df["Name"] thing?

Comment: @GuardGoose - It pass Series, not column name. If want pass column name, need string.